# How can i send xml data to the server using HttpService request thr POST in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex

please tell me the examples.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex Side:

```
import mx.rpc.http.HTTPService;
import mx.rpc.AsyncToken;
import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

var service:HTTPService = new HTTPService;
service.useProxy = false;
service.method = "post";
service.url = "[your php]";
var params:Object = {};
params.xml = "[your xml string] <root><label = "hello world" /></root>";
var token:AsyncToken = service.send(params);
var responder:mx.rpc.Responder = new mx.rpc.Responder(onResult, onFault);
token.addResponder(responder);

private function onResult(event:ResultEvent):void{
     trace ("XML PASSED", event.result);
}
private function onFault(event:FaultEvent):void{
     trace ("XML PASSING FAILED");
}
```

PHP SIDE

```
$Data = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$result = $Data->children();
$totalrow = count($result);

for ($i = 0; $i < $totalrow; $i++ ){
   echo "This is the output:".$result[$i]['label'];
}
```

Please check for some minor errors.. Hope it helps

**Note:trace can only be viewed on debug mode in Flex**